# Django inherited model instance creation function

Tags: django, inheritance, django-managers

Say I have the following, `Model_1` has 1 integer, `Model_2` inherits `Model_1` and adds another integer.

```
class Model_1Manager (models.Manager):
  def create (self, i)
    m = self.model(value1=i)
    m.save()

class Model_1 (models.Model):
  value1 = model.IntegerField()
  objects = Model_1Manager()

class Model_2Manager (Model_1Manager):
  def create (self, i1, i2)
    m = self.model(value1=i1, value2=i2)
    m.save()

class Model_2 (Model_1):
  value2 = model.IntegerField()
  objects = Model_2Manager()
```

Questions:

1. Is the `create()` function in `Model_2Manager` written correctly as is?
2. Is there some way for me to call `Model_1Manager`'s `create()` function?? How would that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the `create()` function in `Model_2Manager` written correctly as is?

It is.

> Is there some way for me to call `Model_1Manager`'s `create()` function?? How would that work?

Unfortunately in this case `Model_1Manager.create()` does not do enough to initialize a `Model_2`, so you should not attempt to call it.

Comment: Hmm... I guess it also does not make any sense to inherit managers either. What I should probably do is make Model_1 abstract, NOT define a manager for it, and then just define a manager for Model_2.